PHP code for sending an email is not working even with updated code from the PHP website
I am writing some code that is supposed to send a confirmation of purchase email to customers when their purchase is registered. This code uses a mix of HTML, PHP, and pulling data from MySQL database. My PHP is currently not working. I have come to multiple links here already, and used the code from the PHP site on how to do this. However, I when testing with my own email as the recipient, I am not getting any emails, or they go to junk.
$headers = NULL;
$headers = ‘MIME-Version: 1.0’ . “\r\n”;
$headers .= ‘Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1’ . “r/n/”;
$headers .= “Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit”. “/r/n”;


$headers .= ‘From:  Shipment Confirmation <customerservice@company.com>’ . “\r\n”;


$headers .= ‘Bcc: boss@company.net’ . “\r\n”;


mail($email_receipients, $subject, $output, $headers, “-fcustomerservice@company.com”);

I have (obviously) edited names here to not give away any information on the company. However, they are correct in the code I am running. Also, variables in the "mail" function are all defined by whoever developed the original code. Some emails show up in my junk (as mentioned) so I know that the code should at least run to send emails there. However, this current iteration is not sending anything to junk. This section is the only part that I have messed with. Any ideas? Thanks!

It has become really hard to send casual emails from web servers. Because spam-creeps. The big email services -- grmail among them -- just summarily block stuff from untrusted senders. You may have to set yourself up with an email service provider account and use their SMTP server. sendgrid.com has a reasonably good free tier.

to send mail reliably to gmail and, increasingly, many other mail providers, you need to make sure your mailserver has DKIM, DMARC, SPF all set up, and meet various other requirements. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78484521/5947043 . This is all in the ongoing fight against spam, spoofing, phishing and so on which has blighted email services for decades.

Turns out I was overcomplicating it. the mail function works since there is a mail server set up for the company. Thank you for the help though!
